# NGINX удалить часть урла, известно только что должно остаться?

Tags: nginx, php-nginx

Доброго времени суток, помогите пожалуйста. Есть урлы:

```
/asdas/asdas/cat/loans/express/
/asd/cat/loans/express/
/asasas/asa/aaa/cat/loans/hypotech
```

Нужно чтобы всё это редиректило, чтобы в начале перед `/cat` ничего не было, но всё, что после `/cat/` сохранялось.

Так не работает:

```
location / {
  rewrite ^(.*)(\/cat\/.*)$ $2 last;
}
```

И так не работает:

```
location / {
  rewrite ^(.*)(/cat/.*)$ $2 last;
}
```